# How can I change a SQL query result to a superfish dropdown menu?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I've been working on a project for months and i stuck in the mud. Suffering from tunnel vision.

The question is; I'm using that query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `kgsim_towns`.`name` as town, `kgsim_districts`.`name` as district, `status`, `category`, `type`, `attribute`
FROM (`ad_general`)
LEFT JOIN `kgsim_towns` ON `kgsim_towns`.`id` = `ad_general`.`town`
LEFT JOIN `kgsim_districts` ON `kgsim_districts`.`id` = `ad_general`.`district`
```

And getting that as result (it's more than that but that's enough for giving you idea):

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Menteş
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[1] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Mezitli
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[2] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Limonlu
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 6
)

[3] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Ellinciyıl
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[4] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Menderes
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 6
)

[5] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Ellinciyıl
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 9
)

[6] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Akdeniz
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[7] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Pirireis
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 17
)

[8] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Viranşehir
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[9] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Batıkent
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[10] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Akkent
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[11] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Güvenevler
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 6
)

[12] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Fatih
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[13] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Menderes
[status] => 2
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 2
)

[14] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Davultepe
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[15] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Yenidistrict
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[16] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Tece
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 2
)

[17] => Array
(
[town] => Yenişehir
[district] => Fuatmorel
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[18] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Fatih
[status] => 2
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 4
)

[19] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Viranşehir
[status] => 1
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 6
)

[20] => Array
(
[town] => Mezitli
[district] => Menderes
[status] => 2
[category] => 1
[type] => 9
[attribute] => 6
)

)
```

I want to build a [superfish menu](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample1) like that:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    Choose Category
            <ul>
                <li>
                Town 1
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        District 1
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        Status 1
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    Category 1 
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li>
                                                                Type 9 
                                                                    <ul>
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            attiribute 6
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>Status 2</li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>District 2</li>
                        <li>District 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Town 2</li>
                <li>Town 3</li>
                <li>Etc</li>
            </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

The question is how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Rebuild a new array and use a recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have completed the function. Probably it's not the best way to do it, for example, probably no need to run array_unique function for each row. But still, the only working solution so far.

```
function superfish($array = array(), $array_language) {
foreach ($array as $key => $option) {
// town start
$town = $option['town'];
$array_new['town'][$key] = $town;
$array_new['town_unique'] = array_unique($array_new['town']);
// town finish

// district start
$district = $option['district'];
$town_district = $array_new['town'][$key];
$town_district .= "_district";
$town_district_unique = $town_district."_unique";
$array_new[$town_district][$key] = $district;
$array_new[$town_district_unique] = array_unique($array_new[$town_district]);
// district finish

// status start
$status = $option['status'];
$town_district_status = $town."_".$district."_status";
$town_district_status_unique = $town_district_status."_unique";
$array_new[$town_district_status][$key] = $status;
$array_new[$town_district_status_unique] = array_unique($array_new[$town_district_status]);
// status finish

// category start
$category = $option['category'];
$town_district_status_category = $town."_".$district."_".$status."_category";
$town_district_status_category_unique = $town_district_status_category."_unique";
$array_new[$town_district_status_category][$key] = $category;
$array_new[$town_district_status_category_unique] = array_unique($array_new[$town_district_status_category]);
// category finish

// type start
$type = $option['type'];
$town_district_status_category_type = $town."_".$district."_".$status."_".$category."_type";
$town_district_status_category_type_unique = $town_district_status_category_type."_unique";
$array_new[$town_district_status_category_type][$key] = $type;
$array_new[$town_district_status_category_type_unique] = array_unique($array_new[$town_district_status_category_type]);
// type finish

// özellik start
$attribute = $option['attribute'];
$town_district_status_category_type_attribute = $town."_".$district."_".$status."_".$category."_".$type."_attribute";
$town_district_status_category_type_attribute_unique = $town_district_status_category_type_attribute."_unique";
$array_new[$town_district_status_category_type_attribute][$key] = $attribute;
$array_new[$town_district_status_category_type_attribute_unique] = array_unique($array_new[$town_district_status_category_type_attribute]);     
// özellik finish


/*  $array_new['town']['district'][$key] = $option['district'];
$array_new['town']['district']['status'][$key] = $option['status'];
$array_new['town']['district']['status']['category'][$key] = $option['category'];
$array_new['town']['district']['status']['category']['type'] = $option['type'];
$array_new['town']['district']['status']['category']['type']['attribute'] = $option['attribute']; */
}

if(is_array($array_new['town_unique'])) {
// $array_superfish = "<div class=\"navbar\">";
$array_superfish = "<ul>";

foreach ($array_new['town_unique'] as $town) {
$array_superfish .= "<li><a><span class=\"menu-title\">";
$array_superfish .= $town;  
$array_superfish .= "</span></a>";
$town_district_unique = $town."_district_unique";
    if(is_array($array_new[$town_district_unique])) {
    $array_superfish .= "<ul>";
        foreach ($array_new[$town_district_unique] as $district) {
        $array_superfish .= "<li><a><span class=\"menu-title\">";
        $array_superfish .= $district;
        $array_superfish .= "</span></a>";
        $town_district_status_unique = $town."_".$district."_status_unique";
            if(is_array($array_new[$town_district_status_unique])) {
            $array_superfish .= "<ul>";
                foreach ($array_new[$town_district_status_unique] as $status) { 
                $array_superfish .= "<li><a><span class=\"menu-title\">";
                $array_superfish .= $array_language[11][$status];
                $array_superfish .= "</span></a>";
                $town_district_status_category_unique = $town."_".$district."_".$status."_category_unique";
                    if(is_array($array_new[$town_district_status_category_unique])) {
                    $array_superfish .= "<ul>";
                        foreach ($array_new[$town_district_status_category_unique] as $category) {
                        $array_superfish .= "<li><a><span class=\"menu-title\">";
                        $array_superfish .= $array_language[21][$category];
                        $array_superfish .= "</span></a>";
                        $town_district_status_category_type_unique = $town."_".$district."_".$status."_".$category."_type_unique";
                            if(is_array($array_new[$town_district_status_category_type_unique])) {
                            $array_superfish .= "<ul>";
                                foreach ($array_new[$town_district_status_category_type_unique] as $type) {
                                if($category==3 or $category==NULL)
                                $category = 2;  
                                $type_code = ''.$category.'31';
                                $array_superfish .= "<li><a><span class=\"menu-title\">";
                                $array_superfish .= $array_language[$type_code][$type];
                                $array_superfish .= "</span></a>";
                                $town_district_status_category_type_attribute_unique = $town."_".$district."_".$status."_".$category."_".$type."_attribute_unique";
                                    if(is_array($array_new[$town_district_status_category_type_attribute_unique])) {
                                    $array_superfish .= "<ul>";
                                        foreach ($array_new[$town_district_status_category_type_attribute_unique] as $attribute) {
                                            $array_superfish .= "<li><a><span class=\"menu-title\">";
                                            $genel_attribute_code = $array_language[101][$category]*10+2;
                                            $genel_attribute_metin = $array_language[$genel_attribute_code][$attribute];    
                                            $array_superfish .= $array_language[$genel_attribute_code][$attribute];
                                            $array_superfish .= "</span></a>";
                                            $array_superfish .= "</li>";
                                        }
                                    $array_superfish .= "</ul>";
                                    }

                                $array_superfish .= "</li>";    
                                }
                            $array_superfish .= "</ul>";
                            }
                        $array_superfish .= "</li>";
                        }
                    $array_superfish .= "</ul>";
                    }
                $array_superfish .= "</li>";
                }
            $array_superfish .= "</ul>";
            }
        $array_superfish .= "</li>";
        }
    $array_superfish .= "</ul>";
    }
$array_superfish .= "</li>";
}
$array_superfish .= "</ul>";
}   
//  $array_superfish .= "</div>";
return $array_superfish;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First approach

Modify select to include order by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   `kgsim_towns`.`name` as town, 
   `kgsim_districts`.`name` as district, 
   `status`, 
   `category`, 
   `type`, 
   `attribute`
FROM (`ad_general`)
LEFT JOIN `kgsim_towns` ON `kgsim_towns`.`id` = `ad_general`.`town`
LEFT JOIN `kgsim_districts` ON `kgsim_districts`.`id` = `ad_general`.`district`
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Write array of arrays (I write it in pseudo code, sorry):

```
previous_town = ''
previous_district = ''
for each row in results:
   if previus_town != row.town
      array[row.town] = array()
      previous_town = row.town
      previous_district = ''
   if preious_district != row.district
      array[row.town][row.district] = array()
      previous_district = row.district
   ...
```

at this time you have an array of arrays of arrays ...

Now create a recursive function that transform this to `<ul><li>`. Some thing like this.
(I write it in pseudo code, sorry):

```
function toli( array ) {

   str = "<ul>"
   for each key, value in array
     str += "<li>" + key +
            iif( value is array, toli(value), value )
            + "</li>"
   str += "</ul>

}
```

**Edited, Easy way**

To reduce problem complexity you can create menu in nested loops:
Insteat to make a single big query, you should split this query in several littles querys as:

```
$str = '<ul><li>Choose Category<ul>'
SELECT DISTINCT 
   `kgsim_towns`.`name` as town
FROM (`ad_general`)
LEFT JOIN `kgsim_towns` ON `kgsim_towns`.`id` = `ad_general`.`town`
LEFT JOIN `kgsim_districts` ON `kgsim_districts`.`id` = `ad_general`.`district`
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
For each $town selected:
   $str = $str . '<li>' . $town . '<ul>'
   SELECT DISTINCT 
       `kgsim_districts`.`name` as district
   FROM (`ad_general`)
   LEFT JOIN `kgsim_towns` ON `kgsim_towns`.`id` = `ad_general`.`town`
   LEFT JOIN `kgsim_districts` ON `kgsim_districts`.`id` = `ad_general`.`district`
   WHERE
      `kgsim_towns`.`name` = $town
   ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
   For each $district selected:
      $str = $str . '<li>' . $district . '<ul>'
      SELECT DISTINCT 
       `status`
      FROM (`ad_general`)
      LEFT JOIN `kgsim_towns` ON `kgsim_towns`.`id` = `ad_general`.`town`
      LEFT JOIN `kgsim_districts` ON `kgsim_districts`.`id` = `ad_general`.`district`
      WHERE
        `kgsim_towns`.`name` = $town and
       `kgsim_districts`.`name` = $district
      ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
      For each $status selected:
         $str = $str . '<li>' . $status . '<ul>'

         //etc for category, type attribute ...

         $str = $str . '</ul>' //close status ul

      $str = $str . '</ul>'  //close district ul

   $str = $str . '</ul>'  //close town ul
```

Comment: at first i want to tell, wow! i wasn't aware that i can use multiple values at the same time in order by clause. thanks for that tipp. second, the last recursive function is also helps and very clever but the pseudo code in the middle, it's a little bit confusing i think i didn't get it but working on it though.

Comment: @motto, you can fill str string in nested loops, more easy. Need help?

Comment: any help will be appreciated, still not much success, i am starting to think there is a curse with that problem.

Comment: I edited answer to achive it in a more easy way. I hope this solve your issue.

Comment: i'm working on different solution and also i took a part from your answer too. i'll post the answer as soon as i finish it.

Comment: i have posted my solution probably it's not the best way to do it, but i think, i should choose a solution without multiple sql queries. Because of the performance. But i have to say that I have used your sql query code.